# How to update code snippet Lambda call S3 event with AWS's Java SDK v2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

JDK 21. Dependencies

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

source sample at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

```java
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Handler.class);

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
        try {
            S3EventNotificationRecord record = s3event.getRecords().get(0);
            String srcBucket = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
            String srcKey = record.getS3().getObject().getUrlDecodedKey();

            S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().build();
            HeadObjectResponse headObject = getHeadObject(s3Client, srcBucket, srcKey);

            logger.info("Successfully retrieved " + srcBucket + "/" + srcKey + " of type " + headObject.contentType());

            return "Ok";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private HeadObjectResponse getHeadObject(S3Client s3Client, String bucket, String key) {
        HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .key(key)
                .build();
        return s3Client.headObject(headObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I suspect you are missing the aws-lambda-java-events dependency, see: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/main/aws-lambda-java-events/README.md